# Dynamically generated style sheet based on the clients parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node.js and I'm wondering if there's a module that would generate custom stylesheets based on clients window size and other paramerers. Those parameters would be used in the stylesheet template by the programer like variables.

I realize that the server might not have that info about the client so if there isn't a serverside solution, is there at least a client side one I could use?

Comment: The different window sizes can be handled with CSS and media queries. The other preferences might be able to be stored in the database on the generate the necessary stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**media queries** would be more elegant solution for you quest.

But if you want to achieve you task with plain js,try this

```
var parameter_one = "http: //stackoverflow.com/one.css";  //your absolute path
var parameter_two = "http: //stackoverflow.com/two.css";

if (screen.width < 1024) {
    load_me(parameter_one)
} else {
    load_me(parameter_two)
}

function load_me(file) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = file;
    link.media = 'all';
    head.appendChild(link);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know about media querries. It seems odd to me to limit them to conditionals only. Is there no way to access those media feature variables in CSS? I guess it's a pointless question since CSS has no mathematical operators to use those variables.

Comment: @LukaHorvat:i am not much in to media queries though its quite popular among designers these days..this nswer is our good old method!!!